# How can I set an incremental value to a TextBox?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to set a range of values going from `1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, 3.1, 3.2 ... 50.2` and make them incremental.

The goal is to make the value on the TextBox change to the next one on the list everytime I hit a button to validate my data.

And I need to "bind" those values to a date, so I can't repeat it on the same day.

For example. I have a filled form and the textbox value is `2.1` on `30/10/2017`. I validate my data and restart the process, and now the value is `2.2` and I can't repeat `2.1`, because I'm still on `30/10/2017`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Could you save the state in the registry after each invocation of your validation routine?

Then the next time the form is loaded, get the data out of the registry?

For more information on using the registry to store VBA settings see

http://sourcedaddy.com/ms-excel/saving-application-settings-registry.html

Comment: I've done some research on what you suggested and found a partial solution to my problem.

However, I'm still not sure how I'm going to make the value go from 1.2 to 1.2 to 2.1 to 2.2 and so on.

Should I create some kind of list or something?

Comment: Either a list, or store the major and minor numbers separately and decide in code which should be incremented

Comment: Can you explain it to me really quick? I'm googling that info but for some reason I can't understand a single thing of what I'm looking at. :\

Comment: How about changing your initial question to add in all the things that you've tried so then people can see your steps and can also help?